# Seismic wavefield theory: velocity anisotropy

Tags: seismic

Does the [reciprocity principle](http://sepwww.stanford.edu/sep/prof/bei/sg/paper_html/node7.html) hold true in an [anisotropic](https://wiki.seg.org/wiki/Seismic_anisotropy) subsurface environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, or at least certainly in theory. If you look up any derivation of the *elastodynamic representation theorem* you're bound to find that it holds for the most general version of the elastic wave equation:
\begin{align}\rho \frac{\partial^2 u_i(x,t)}{\partial t^2}& = \frac{\partial \sigma_{ij}}{\partial x_j} \\ \sigma_{ij}(x,t) & = c_{ijkl}(x)\varepsilon_{kl}(x,t)\end{align}
with $u$ the displacement, $\sigma$ the stress, $\rho$ the density and $c_{ijkl}$ Hooke's tensor. You'll have run into this tensor whenever you researched anisotropy, because it is how one describes anisotropy.

The main reference is a book by Aki & Richards (1982): https://www.ldeo.columbia.edu/~richards/Aki_Richards.html , but it is also derived in these handouts, see the bottom of page 15: http://www.geo.uu.nl/~paulssen/Theoreticalseismology/handout.pdf .

The notation $G_{nm}(\xi_2,\tau|\xi_1,t)= G_{mn}(\xi_1,\tau|\xi_2,t)$ is the reciprocity relation. $G_{nm}(\xi_2,\tau|\xi_1,t)$ is the measured displacement due to a point source in direction $m$ at time $t$ at location $\xi_1$ as measured at time $\tau$ at $\xi_2$ in direction $n$. The reciprocity relation says that this recorded signal is identical to an experiment where a source in direction $n$ at time $t$ at location $\xi_2$ is measured at time $\tau$ at $\xi_1$ in direction $m$. Hence, you can interchange source and receiver when you interchange source and receiver dirctions too.